# QDesktopServices::openUrl(). Не открывается путь к сетевому диску

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Пытаюсь открыть путь к сетевому диску следующим образом:

```
        QString filePath = "//Camera20/data/";
        QUrl url;
        if (filePath.startsWith("\\\\") || filePath.startsWith("//"))
        {
            url.setUrl(QDir::toNativeSeparators(filePath));
        }

        else
        {
            url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(filePath);
        }
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
```

Но попытка оканчивается провалом. В выводе пишется следующая ошибка:

```
ShellExecute '%5C%5CCamera20%5Cdata%5C' failed (error 2).
```

Как это исправить? win7, qt 5.9.4

Comment: Интересно, а если просто `QDesktopServices::openUrl("//Camera20/data/");`?

Comment: @gil9red, не-а, пишет "ShellExecute '//camera20/data/' failed (error 2)."

Comment: А если так `QDesktopServices::openUrl("file:////Camera20/data/");` / `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("//Camera20/data/"));`?

Comment: @gil9red, ситуация немного изменилась: "ShellExecute 'file:///%5C%5CCamera20/data/' failed (error 3)"

Comment: Для обоих вариантов ошибка 3?

Comment: @gil9red, file:////Camera20/data/ - работает. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автору помогло:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl("file:////Camera20/data/");

QString filePath = "//Camera20/data/";
QDesktopServices::openUrl("file://" + filePath);
```